# Setting up MEAN webserver in Ubuntu 14.04 vm

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, webserver, node.js

I'm new to the world of web servers. My lab gave me a url with a Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. I sorted out enough of what I needed to do to SSH in, install all relevant libraries, and clone my code via git.

Ultimately, my goal is to have the app (a pretty standard [MEAN webapp](http://mean.io/#!/)) available at the same url the vm is hosted at.

I haven't been able to find any resources to describe what to do next. I know I need to start up mongodb and the node server, and sort out DNS. I'm just not quite sure how to go about all of it.

How do I wire everything up?

Comment: Does your vm have a hostname that is resolving or do you want to just reach it via its IP address?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516497/how-to-deploy-mean-js-node-js-application-to-production-environment) out on stackoverflow on how to deploy a production MEAN server. Not sure I would use `node` for your production web server. They recommend `nginx` or `varnish` in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to comment, but I can't. This is a difficult question to answer because you haven't provided much detail about what your goal is. What is your end goal? What kind of code have you written?

EDIT: Now we're getting somewhere.

For DNS, you'll want to talk to the IT department or lab manager, as that's going to be managed by someone else, and you will likely have to provide them with the IP of your VM and your desired hostname, but YMMV.

Aside from that, I'll point you to this detailed how-to for setting up the MEAN stack on ubuntu 14.04:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mean-js-stack-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

Comment: It's a MEAN webapp. When I run the code locally (on a OSX dev environment), I simply start mongo and npm start and runs. The end goal is for the web app to be accessible to the public at the url the vm is hosted at. Does that help?